# add label before class in jQuery function

Tags: jquery, css, label

Every time a text is entered in my form, the label name disapears e.g. "Name", "Surname" etc and goes from display:block to display:none.I want to overide this using jQuery and have tried the following function that doesn't work. Here is a link to the page in question: https://www.apis.de/anmeldung-zum-benutzertreffen/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('label.gfield_label').css('display','block','opacity','1');
});
```

Comment: Please add the code here, not just a link to a page. Also, you may want to find the code the does that an modify there, not just write the code like that to overwrite it.

Comment: *Why* does the label disappear?  Would it not make sense to stop that functionality rather than "override" it?

Comment: It is an issue with the wordpress theme we are using. Unfortunately i cannot change this theme as it is unique for the company

Comment: How would i override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax for setting multiple properties using `.css()` is by using an object:

```
 jQuery('label.gfield_label').css({
   'display':'block',
   'opacity':'1'
 });
```

But, rather than changing display on the fly, it would make a lot more sense to change or override whatever `CSS` selector is setting your `display` to `none`.

If you can't change the source, you should inspect the currently applying rule and set another rule in your CSS, with a stronger (more specific) CSS selector. Typically, in WordPress, you should use your current theme's `style.css` but please note many WP themes previde at least one way of adding custom `CSS` in dashboard.

---

**Edit:** (on subsequent info) It looks like a script in your page sets `opacity:0` to any label of a field that has been changed and validates. You either find that script and disable it or you could use this `CSS`:

```
#gform_1 li label {
  display: block !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

The proper way to do it would be to find the script, but that's not always trivial. Normally, this should be a setting in whatever plugin/theme script you are using to render the form. While using `!important` will work, it's not recommended.

Comment: Can you tell which selector is doing this?

Comment: Yes, if you can provide a [mcve]. At this point, the URL you provided is not reproducing the problem described in your question.

Comment: Yes. As soon as you enter text in to the box, the name on the left of the box disapears

Comment: I know how to fix this in the dev tools. I select a gfield_label class and on the right hand side under "Rules" i change the "label" from display:block to display:block !important. This stops it from disapearing.

Comment: I edited my answer. You ***can't*** fix this by using `jQuery`, as it's `jQuery` that does it each time you modify a field value. You have to use `!important` in CSS as a practical solution. However, the proper way to fix it is to find the script that does this. It might be a theme or plugin used to render your form. Normally, this should be a setting that can be turned on / off.

Comment: Awesome. What has worked is:```#gform_1 li label {
  opacity: 1 !important;display:block !important;
  }```
~Thank you for your help. Headache over!!!!

Comment: @Dannyboy, if my answer helped you solve the problem, you should consider accepting it. Please note I still think you should look for that setting and turn it ***off***. Happy coding!